# Import paths changed in fesm

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a private library on a git server, which is being imported with package/dist/library-name in another library.

```
import {PdfRenderModule} from 'pdf-render/dist/pdf-render';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        PdfRenderModule
    ]
...
...
```

The library has a service which it adds to the providers in it's module file.

Once I try to import the service in another service

```
import {PdfRenderService} from 'pdf-render/dist/pdf-render';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PdfService {
    constructor(
        public pdfrender: PdfRenderService
    ) {
    }
}
```

the build of the importing lib creates weird paths in the fesm file.

```
import { PdfRenderService as PdfRenderService$1 } from 'pdf-render';
import { PdfRenderService, PdfRenderModule } from 'pdf-render/dist/pdf-render';
```

I have no idea why it changes the import to `'pdf-render';`

It works fine in components though.

Has anyone ever experienced that behaviour?

I expect it to be some tsconfig stuff.

Angular 7 is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `providedIn: 'root'` in PdfService importing PdfRenderService seems to get rid of the weird import.